# Will the Android OS destroy an Application class or AlarmManager class while my app is in background?

Tags: android

I have an `AlarmManager` class, a simple class, an `Application` class and some other class.
The simple class is called by `AlarmManager` and then the simple class try to achieve the goal with the help of `Application` class. It shouldn't matter whether or not my app is in the background; I need to ensure that these three classes are alive.

Now, my question is: **Will the Android OS destroy these three classes (`AlarmManager` class, simple class, `Application` class), if my app is in background?** If the answer is yes, then should I use `Service`? If I use `Service`, how should I implement it with these three classes?

**edited:**

i am trying to post status using facebook sdk in a particular time. So, the `Alarm Manager` class will call the simple class in a particular time. then the simple class will get some data (like session, message) from the `Application` class and then the simple class will post the message to user's wall.

the session , message etc are stored in `Application` class from other activity class.

Comment: If you describe to us what you're trying to do, I'm pretty sure we could help you design it so your app doesn't need to be running in the background and you don't have to use a service.

Comment: Your alarm manager can trigger activity,service or a receiver.No matter application is foreground or background unless you force stop your application.

Comment: @Rasel : ok, so i can extend Service to the `simple class` . but this class need data which are saved in `Application class`. so, **what will happen to the `Application class` if my app is in background?** and how can i start service and stop it after the work is done?

Comment: If you need some data when alarm is triggered, you should save the data to somewhere else. You can use shared preference,sqlite db.You can even write the Application class object to the file.Then you can retrieve that.

Comment: @Rasel : how can i insert session in sq lite db ?

Comment: can you post some code, that will help people to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might want to show some code for clarity. You probably don't have an `AlarmManager` but registered some of your components to be called by creating a `PendingIntent` and passing that to the *system*'s `AlarmManager`. If that assumption is correct, if your app is not running (it doesn't have a live process) at the time the alarm is triggered, Android will create one. 
And in the process load and instantiate all the classes that are used from your component. If your app is in the background (process is still there, 'cached'), Android will reuse that process and call the necessary components.

Answer (score 0):

Android will destroy all (let me name it "apps" here) after some time of inactivity. That includes Activity-objects and Services. The only thing that survives is a Service that is defined as foreground service (will require a notification image in newer versions of Android, so there is no way to hide it completely).

Answer (score -1):

An Activity when in background (by user click Home or system call another activity), it will come onPause(), and it's not continue run, it's mean if your activity is uploading an image -> pause uploading. If system lack of resource like RAM, the system will destroy your activity automatically. So if you want to make an action with long time like download, upload,... you should use the Service.

Or if you want to download by Activity, you can save the download status or somethings like that in onPause() and resumse download in onResume(). But the process of download is not run until you resumse your activity.

Comment: A service itself is NOT enough to ensure it will not be killed by the system, it needs to be a foreground service!

Comment: Yes, but i mean Service can continue process of download or upload when user click Home.